# VBA/Formula logic advice

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a VBA/Formula logic issue which I hope to pick your brains on.

## Step 1

User completes a data table from `Column C Row 2` onward which tells a macro how many times to duplicate the row by per `Column B Row 2`.

I have a formula which then populates `Column A Row 2` with the column header:

```
=IF(COUNTA($B2:$D2)=0,"",INDEX($B$1:$G$1,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISBLANK($B2:$G2),0),0)))
```

The above formula will only populate the first column `Name` which is great if we are not duplicating the rows. However, the issue is that I need to populate the column header of the row that has been duplicated so it looks at the column after the first one of that row.

## Step 2

This is what the finished data table should look like:

**Example**
[image: IMG1]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Const TitleRow As Integer = 1
Const StartGenColumn As Integer = 47  ' AU


Sub GenerateRows()
Dim SrcRow As Integer, DestRow As Integer, SrcCol As Integer
Dim NumCoreColumns As Integer, LastGenColumn As Integer
Dim SrcWS As Worksheet, DestWS As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer


    NumCoreColumns = StartGenColumn - 1
    ' find the last column
    LastGenColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(TitleRow, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' check if it has the totals
    If InStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(TitleRow + 1, LastGenColumn).Formula, "SUM") Then
        LastGenColumn = LastGenColumn - 1
    Else
        ' put in a total so that we can tell when we've finished processing
        ActiveSheet.Cells(TitleRow + 1, LastGenColumn + 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & ColLetter(StartGenColumn) & (TitleRow + 1) & _
                    ":" & ColLetter(LastGenColumn) & (TitleRow + 1) & ")"
        ' fill down
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(TitleRow + 1, LastGenColumn + 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, LastGenColumn + 1)).FillDown
    End If
    Set SrcWS = ActiveSheet

    If LastGenColumn > StartGenColumn Then
        ' create the new worksheet
        Worksheets.Add
        Set DestWS = ActiveSheet

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ' populate the titles
        SrcWS.Range(SrcWS.Cells(TitleRow, 1), SrcWS.Cells(TitleRow, NumCoreColumns)).Copy
        ' always at top of new sheet
        DestWS.Range(DestWS.Cells(1, 1), DestWS.Cells(1, NumCoreColumns)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        SrcRow = TitleRow + 1
        DestRow = 2
        ' while we still have something to do
        Do While SrcWS.Cells(SrcRow, LastGenColumn + 1) <> "" And SrcWS.Cells(SrcRow, LastGenColumn + 1) > 0
            ' copy the core data
            SrcWS.Range(SrcWS.Cells(SrcRow, 1), SrcWS.Cells(SrcRow, NumCoreColumns)).Copy
            ' what to we need to generate
            For SrcCol = StartGenColumn To LastGenColumn
                For i = 1 To SrcWS.Cells(SrcRow, SrcCol).Value
                    DestWS.Range(DestWS.Cells(DestRow, 1), DestWS.Cells(DestRow, NumCoreColumns)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    ' copy in the title and colour
                    DestWS.Cells(DestRow, 1).Value = SrcWS.Cells(TitleRow, SrcCol).Value
                    DestWS.Cells(DestRow, 1).Interior.Color = SrcWS.Cells(TitleRow, SrcCol).Interior.Color
                    DestRow = DestRow + 1
                Next i
            Next SrcCol
            SrcRow = SrcRow + 1
        Loop
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        DestWS.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub


Private Function ColLetter(Col As Integer) As String
Dim Arr
Arr = Split(Cells(1, Col).Address(True, False), "$")
ColLetter = Arr(0)
End Function
```